# How do I find out number of users that authorized my application using Google API?

Tags: google-api

Is there any way to find out number of users that authorized my application using Google API?

User can either install it from the Chrome Web Store or authorize it when going from URL, Chrome Web Store does show number of users who installed it but that most likely doesn't include all users using the app?

Comment: There is no way to see that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can go to your Google Developer Console and check your Quota usage for whatever particular Google API. This can give an indication as to how many users authorized your application through that API, since every time the API is accessed, it will consume quota. Quota resets every day though, so this probably won't give you an all-time number.